# Get posts from multiple tax terms

Tags: wp-query, taxonomy, terms

I'm trying to get related posts by taxonomy term. So a post tagged to 'London' would have related posts tagged to London. The code I have works if the post is tagged to a single taxonomy term only - in this case a single Location (entry_location is the taxonomy). But if I tag it to more than one (eg London and Paris), it returns no results. How do I make it accept multiple tax terms and display results from both?

This is what I have so far. It works for posts tagged with one tax term only.

```
<?php
$this_post = $post->ID;
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'dir_entry', 
    'posts_per_page' => 10, 
    'orderby' => 'date', 
    'order' => 'DESC', 
    'post__not_in' => array($this_post), 
    'entry_location' => get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'entry_location' ))
);
while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
?>
<li class="large-6 columns">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</li>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I honestly don't see how that works at all since [`get_the_term_list`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list) returns an HTML string.

First, you need [`get_the_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) and [`wp_list_pluck`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck).

Second, you need a `tax_query`. That `{tax} = {term}` pattern is deprecated.

```
$this_post = $post->ID;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'dir_entry', 
    'posts_per_page' => 10, 
    'orderby' => 'date', 
    'order' => 'DESC', 
    'post__not_in' => array($this_post), 
  );

$terms = get_the_terms($this_post,'post_tag');
if (!is_wp_error($terms)) {
  $terms = wp_list_pluck($terms,'term_id');
  $args['tax_query'] = array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
      'field' => 'id',
      'terms' => array_values($terms)
    )
  );
  $query = new WP_Query($args);
}
```